# Hadoop master cannot start slave with different $HADOOP_HOME

Tags: hadoop, master-slave

In master, the `$HADOOP_HOME` is `/home/a/hadoop`, the slave's `$HADOOP_HOME` is `/home/b/hadoop`

In master, when I try to using `start-all.sh`, then the master name node start successfuly, but fails to start slave's data node with following message:

```
b@192.068.0.2: bash: line 0: cd: /home/b/hadoop/libexec/..: No such file or directory
b@192.068.0.2: bash: /home/b/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory
```

any idea on how to specify the `$HADOOP_HOME` for slave in master configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to configure different home directories for the various slaves from the master, but the Hadoop FAQ says that the Hadoop framework does not require ssh and that the DataNode and TaskTracker daemons can be started manually on each node.

I would suggest writing you own scripts to start things that take into account the specific environments of your nodes.  However, make sure to include all the slaves in the master's slave file.  It seems that this is necessary and that the heart beats are not enough for a master to add slaves.