# HBase start-hbase.sh fails on second node

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ksh

I try to run HBase on Hadoop in fully distributed mode with two nodes. To start HBase I execute the script start-hbase.sh. The daemons on the master-node, where I execute the script run fine. But on the other node the startup fails:

```
node2.example.com: ksh: cd: /disk/node1/hbase-0.98.4-hadoop2 - No such file or directory
node2.example.com: ksh: /disk/node1/hbase-0.98.4-hadoop2/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: not found
```

Obviously this is because HBase thinks that the $HBASE_HOME-Path is the same on both machines. But this ist not the case (as you can see in the error-message) and I don't have the option to change that.

So here ist my question: Is it possible to say HBase that the $HBASE_HOME-directories are different for each machine?

I am using Hadoop 2.4.1 and HBase 0.98.4 on two FreeBSD machines.

Comment: From your error message it appears than your nodes are using [tag:ksh] not [tag:bash]. I've changed the tags of your question  accordingly. Please review that change and revert it if not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there where no answers for my question until now, I solved the problem by writing my own start-hbase.sh with the correct paths hardcoded in it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12207795/2478880)  solution and adapted it to hbase which config is very similar to hadoop. Its a bit of work for ten machines but works for my purpose.